# Python config file as JSON with inheritance

Tags: python, json, django, inheritance, config

I am looking for library that can easily return configuration object from JSON file, but not just read JSON file and return it - apply inheritance to sections.
Similar what old *.ini or Zend_Config_JSON (from PHP Zend Framework)

Example:

```
{
    "production":{
        "phpSettings":{
            "display_startup_errors": false,
            "display_errors": false
        },
        "includePaths":{
            "library": "APPLICATION_PATH/../library"
        },
        "bootstrap":{
            "path": "APPLICATION_PATH/Bootstrap.php",
            "class": "Bootstrap"
        },
        "appnamespace": "Application",,
        "resources":{
            "frontController":{
                "controllerDirectory": "APPLICATION_PATH/controllers",
                "moduleDirectory": "APPLICATION_PATH/modules",
                "params":{
                    "displayExceptions": false
                }
            },
            "modules":[],
            "db":{
                "adapter": "pdo_sqlite",
                "params":{
                    "dbname": "APPLICATION_PATH/../data/db/application.db"
                }
            },
            "layout":{
                "layoutPath": "APPLICATION_PATH/layouts/scripts/"
            }
        }
    },
    "staging":{
        "_extends": "production"
    },
    "testing":{
        "_extends": "production",
        "phpSettings":{
            "display_startup_errors": true,
            "display_errors": true
        },
    },
    "development":{
        "_extends": "production",
        "resources":{
            "frontController":{
                "params":{
                    "displayExceptions": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As return I would have one of the sections, it section has "_extend" property it would be a this section on top (merge/update) of section that extends.

Is it some library that do it already or python community prefer to handle inheritance differently?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [pyconfigini](https://bitbucket.org/maascamp/pyconfigini), which is config file parser modeled on Zend_Config_Ini

Answer (score -1):

Check this one

```
cfg = JSONConfigParser()

cfg.read_string("""
[section]
number = 3.141592654
dictionary = {"key": "value"}
list = [1,
        2,
        3]
nested = {"list": [1,2,3]}
true = true
none = null

[DEFAULT]
# settings in the default section are inherited
# by all other sections.
default-setting = "default"
""")

# read a setting
cfg.get("section", "number")

# read a setting using index notation
cfg["section"]["true"]

# settings inherited from DEFAULT
cfg.get("section", "default-setting")
```

Inherit here

```
# settings inherited from DEFAULT
cfg.get("section", "default-setting")
```

Ref: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/json-config-parser/0.1.2